# Emacs hangs when I turn on the Tex-source-correlate-mode for AUCTex

Tags: emacs, auctex

After I enabled the Tex-source-correlate-mode, the Emacs would ask me "Start Emacs server for inverse search in viewer?" when I try to open the viewer. But no matter I say "yes" or "no", Emacs simply doesn't respond any more. Any clue about what's going on here?

Comment: Please supply Emacs version / platform / buildnumber etc. Thank you :) `M-x version`

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.12) of 2012-09-22 on panlong, modified by Debian. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now it does respond, but it just show "No source specials in this DVI file - couldn't do reverse search". What am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Can you view it in `xdvi` ?

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Thanks a lot, Slomojo!